# Scheduled timestamp inside of tables

Tags: org-mode, org-table, timestamped

I am creating a table for the upcoming winter season of anime and when I try to insert scheduled timestamps into the table for release dates it automatically pushes the timestamp under the nearest headline.

Is there a way to change this behavior? Or maybe a timestamp that is more fitted for using inside of tables, that will also add the date to my calendar?

Inserting an active timestamp inside of the table works, but what is the difference between that and a scheduled timestamp?

Comment: It might help if you say exactly what you've tried, e.g., a recipe of what you did.

Comment: I am beginning to realize that I don't have much of an understanding of the calendar or agenda tools in Org. I am considering deleting this question. Could you give some advice on what the proper thing to do in this situation in the Emacs Stack Exchange community?

Comment: If you want to delete your question you can. If you don't think it will help anyone else, then consider doing that. On the other hand, maybe you just need to rephrase it to better represent what you want to know. When you click `Ask Question` I think you see some helpful links at the right that should help you pose the questions you really want to pose. Note: if someone answered your question and you think that Q&A could help others then you might not want to delete it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Since someone has already answered the question, I'll find a way to make the question worth keeping up.

Comment: What does "add the date to my calendar" mean? What calendar is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try an *active*  timestamp: `C-c .` (or `C-u C-c .` for an active timestamp with a time). That will be included in your agenda on the dates specified in the timestamps (more than once if there are multiple timestamps with the same date).

EDIT: There are active timestamps and inactive timestamps. Active timestamps are delimited with angle brackets in the buffer:`<2022-12-11 Sun>`. Inactive timestamps are delimited with square brackets: `[2022-12-11 Sun]`. The difference between them is that active timestamps will get the headline in which they are found into that day's agenda, whereas inactive timestamps will do nothing: as far as Org mode is concerned, they are just some text sitting on the page.

`SCHEDULED` timestamps and `DEADLINE` timestamps are both active timestamps that will get the headline in which they are found into the agenda, but not only on the day that the timestamp says but on other days also.

For `SCHEDULED` timestamps, the entry will first appear on the agenda on the day the timestamp specifies, but in addition, it will also appear on subsequent days, until the entry is marked `DONE`. IOW, scheduling the entry for a given day will get you a reminder on that day to start working on it, and on subsequent days to continue working on it, until it is done. It then disappears from the agenda. The agenda also shows you how many days this entry has been in the agenda, "guilting" you into doing something about it.

For `DEADLINE` timestamps, the entry will appear on the agenda on the day the timestmap specifies, but it will also appear on *earlier* days (the number is configurable), reminding you that the deadline is approaching. If you don't get it done by the deadline, then it drops you through a hole in the floor into a vat of hot oil - kidding. If you don't get it done by the deadline (i.e. mark it `DONE` or `CANCELED` or some other keyword that you have specified to be a `DONE` state), then it will continue to nag you on subsequent days as well, just like a `SCHEDULED` item.

The difference between these two styles of timestamp is that with `SCHEDULED`, you tell it when you want to start work on it, with `DEADLINE` when you want to finish work on it. See [Deadlines and Scheduling](https://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-Scheduling.html) in the Org mode manual.

Both of these are syntactically required to be right after the headline (that's why when you try to enter a `SCHEDULED` timestamp into your table, Org mode enters it after the headline).

As the above link to the manual states, you don't use a `SCHEDULED` timestamp to e.g. schedule a meeting. `SCHEDULED` means something else in Org mode: when you want to start working on an item. To schedule a meeting, you just use a plain active timestamp: no `SCHEDULED` and no `DEADLINE`.

Comment: This didn't add the event to my calendar.

I am beginning to realize that I don't have much of a grasp on org's calendar or agenda tools. I think this question may be putting the cart before the horse. Your reputation score is pretty high, would you recommend deleting this question for now until I gain a better understanding and try to solve this on my own?

Comment: I think the question has merit, so I don't think you should delete it. Besides, somebody might come up with better ideas if they see it and they won't see it if you delete it :-) You might want to enhance the question though, with more details about your org mode file and what calendar integration you are using (Org mode itself does not have a calendar as such: it has the agenda for things to do on specific dates and it uses the `calendar` application that's built-in to Emacs when you have to pick a date - is that what you mean?) Please edit the question and add any such details.

Comment: Sorry that I am just getting back to this. When I said "add to calendar" I meant Org's built in calendar/agenda. Which I now realize needs to be told to scan certain org files to get the information.  I think I got a bit in over my head with a bunch of packages and such. I'm starting over again with a fresh install of Emacs and will be focusing on one thing at a time. Org mode is definitely the most important tool for me, so that'll be one of the first things I customize. But I think I get it now. Active=include in agenda, inactive=buffer only, file must be included in agenda scan.

Comment: What I'm not entirely sure about is what the difference between an active timestamp and a scheduled timestamp is. I know that deadline will give me a two week heads up about a task but what exactly is the difference between those other two?

Comment: Added some info and a reference to the answer: HTH.